# If statement not working how I want it to

Tags: c++

The following C++ code:

```
if (a != '0.5' || a != '0.6')
{
    cout << "The answer is neither 0.5 nor 0.6 " << '\n';
}
```

I have also tried

```
if ((a != '0.5') || (a != '0.6'))
{
   cout << "The answer is neither 0.5 nor 0.6 " << '\n';
}
```

and tried

```
if ( !(a== '0.5') || !(a==0.6)
{
     cout << "The answer is neither 0.5 nor 0.6 " << '\n';
}
```

Receives a number from a user and checks if the number is 0.5 or 0.6; if it is it should execute as a false statement but if it's any other number it should execute as true. However, it keeps executing as true though it should execute as false when I enter 0.5 or 0.6. This is different when I use an else if statement in which it works fine that is:

```
if (a != 0.5)
{
    //what to do if true.
}
else if (a != 0.6)
{
    //What to do if this is true and the first id wrong.
}
else
{
    //What to do if none are true.
}
```

Why can't the != execute in the if statement?

Comment: Okay I didn't mean for the code to end up looking like that.

Comment: okay just how does one use the if (a != 'x' || a != 'y') {} statement is all I want to know. Without the else please

Answer (score 3):

The logic is wrong. You are currently checking whether a number is not 0.5 or not 0.6 at the same time; all numbers will pass that test. You need to replace the logical-or (`||`) with a logical-and (`&&`).

Also, you need to remove the single quotes from the numbers otherwise you are creating a multicharacter literal which has an implementation defined value.

```
if (a != 0.5 && a != 0.6)
{
    cout << "The answer is neither 0.5 nor 0.6 " << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a is supposed to be a float or a string ? In either way, this syntax is wrong '0.5', if it's a string use double quotes. Don't compare with float/double for (in)equality, because of the internal representation this won't work as you expect, see [how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats).

Comment: @MosesMwaniki but is it supposed to be a floating point number or a string literal?

Answer (score 1):

What's the type of *a*?

## std::string

suppose:

```
std::string a;
std::cin >> a;
```

then the following code works:

```
if (a == "0.5" || a == "0.6")
{
    // Do something when it's true
}
else
{
    // Do something when it's false
}
```

Although "0.5" and "0.6" are *const char**, they will convert to *std::string*, so it works well.

## const char *

```
char a[BUFSIZE];
std::cin >> a;
if (strcmp(a, "0.5") == 0 || strcmp(a, "0.6") == 0)
{
  // Do something when it's true
}
else
{
  // Do something when it's false
}
```

You could use *strcmp* to compare c-style string

## float / double

When you are comparing floats, you may meet precision problems. You could write some functions or a Float class to solve the problem. Like this:

```
const double EPS = 1e-8;
inline bool FloatEqual(const double lhs, const double rhs)
{ return std::fabs(rhs-lhs) <= EPS; }
int main()
{
  double a;
  std::cin >> a;
  if (FloatEqual(a, 0.5) || FloatEqual(a, 0.6))
  {
    // Do something when it's true
  }
  else
  {
    // Do something when it's false
  }
}
```

## By the way

It's interesting to find that the following statements are equal

```
if (a == "0.5" || a == "0.6")
if (!(a != "0.5" && a != "0.6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes from 0.5 and 0.6 and you should be using &&(AND) not ||(OR) i.e.:
`if (a != 0.5 && a != 0.6)`

Answer (score 0):

It must be

```
if (a != 0.5 && a != 0.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is a char then odd things will happen when you do somthing like:

```
char a = '0.5';
cout << "A: " a << endl;
```

This will output (on my compiler, cant be sure about any others):

```
A: 5
```

And:

```
char a = '0.5';
if (a == '5')
    cout << "yey" << endl;
else
    cout << "oops" << endl;
```

This will output:

```
yey
```

But i think this behaviour is undefined (i don't know for sure). At any rate it won't do what you seem to think it will.

Secondly i think your logic is wrong:

You are saying:

If not `0.5` OR not `0.6`

Where i think you mean

If not `0.5` AND not `0.6`

```
if (a != '0.5' && a != '0.6')
```