# round floating point in python e+23

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I have float value as follow:

```
6.07345232904e+23
```

How can I convert this to two decimal places?

I have tried with `round()`.
But it is not working.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940627/50065

Comment: What do you want exactly? `607[... 20 digits here].xy` or `6.07e+23`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: I want to compare two values 6.07345232904e+23 and 2.07386846826e+23

I have written the code as follows:
def compare(x, y):
        a = float(x.hash)
        b = float(y.hash)
        c = float("{0:.2f}".format(a))  
        d=float("{0:.2f}".format(b))
        if c > d: 
            return d/c
        return c/d

Comment: why do you round the values to compare? [How to correctly and standardly compare floats?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4548004/995714) [Most effective way for float and double comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17333/995714) https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/doubles-are-not-floats-so-dont-compare-them/ http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: You probably have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask how to compare, not how to round

Answer (score 4):

You can't. That value is approximately 607345232904000000000000, which already has more than two decimal places. If you want the *representation* to have two decimal places then you must specify that.

```
>>> '{:.3g}'.format(6.07345232904e+23)
'6.07e+23'
```

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your clarification of what you actually want to do, namely comparing two numbers with a given precision:

There are different ways to do this, depending on what your criteria are. The simplest solution is

```
abs(a-b) <= tolerance
```

If you are using Python 3.5, you can use [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose). For earlier version, this should be functionally equivalent

```
def isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
  return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
```

If you really need to handle all corner cases, you will have to to [some additional work](https://github.com/PythonCHB/close_pep/blob/master/is_close.py).