# doubles not comparing c++

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing a c++ function to locate a given double from a matrix (ie return the indices, as (i,j)).
this is the function i have written :

```
std::pair<int,int> locate(std::vector<std::vector<double> >&t, double d) {
 std::pair<int,int> p = make_pair(0,0); // initialising
 cout<<"double given : "<<d<<"\n";
 for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < t[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        if (d==t[i][j])
        {
            p = make_pair(i,j);
            cout<<"YES";
            return p;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"NO ";
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
 }
}
```

the given matrix is

```
50400.5 43220.8 46053.4 46700.8 44800.8  
50460.5 43160.8 46293.4 46640.8 44540.8  
50620.5 43220.8 45833.4 46720.8 44480.8
```

and the output i get is

```
double given : 43220.8
NO NO NO NO NO 
NO NO NO NO NO 
NO NO NO NO NO 
43220.8 : 0,0
```

i am invoking it as

```
std::pair<int,int> p;
double d = 43220.8;
p = locate(raw_1_set_man,d); // raw_1_set_man is the matrix
cout<<"43220.8 : "<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<"\n";
```

Control is not entering the if block
where did i do wrong?

Comment: You can't compare floating point values with equals. Read this: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats)

Comment: Got it. Thank, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare using epsilon:

```
bool doubleEqual(double d1, double d2, double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon())
{
    return d1 <= d2 + epsilon && d1 + epsilon >= d2;
}
```

or some epsilon that is better fitting for your purpose. Please be cautious with this method, though, and also consider the comments to this answer and the comments to the question.

Comment: How to pick a suitable epsilon please?

Comment: I have made an edit, std::numeric_limits offers an epsilon. Also, whoever downvotes could please give a reason

Comment: Even comparison with `numeric_limits` is wrong. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) and [this](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).

Comment: The sources state that you have to be careful, not that it is wrong in itself. What you seem to mean is: Be careful when using those solutions because - depending on context - they might lead to wrong results

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't downvote.  1) OP's values are **far** from 1.0. So using epsilon is asking for trouble. What could be used, but the OP must check the use case, are: [std::nextafter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) and std::nexttoward

Comment: Well, yes, of course, that's correct. Sometimes you even want `flt1 == flt2`, but in most times you don't want that. And it's most likely not the case here. The `numeric_limits` is the minimum value between two representable floats between 0 and 1 on the current machine. OP wants a comparison using ULP.

Comment: comparison with `numeric_limits` is not working, a suitable epsilon chosen by me is working and is fine by me. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: yes, depending on the purpose a larger epsilon might work, that is highly case-dependant. Thanks also for Leandros' and fjardon's valuable comments