# Leetcode May Challenge : Check If It Is a Straight Line

Tags: c++, casting, double

Here is my code for the problem :  Check If It Is a Straight Line

```
 bool checkStraightLine(vector<vector<int>>& a) {
        double m = (((double)a[1][1]-a[0][1])/(a[1][0]-a[0][0]));

        for(int i=1;i<a.size()-1;i++)
        {

                double slope=(((double)a[i][1]-a[i+1][1])/(a[i][0]-a[i+1][0]));

                if( m!=slope)
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My doubt is why does my code produce an error when I replace :

```
double m = (((double)a[1][1]-a[0][1])/(a[1][0]-a[0][0]));
```

with

```
double m = (double)((a[1][1]-a[0][1])/(a[1][0]-a[0][0]));
```

and

```
double slope=(((double)a[i][1]-a[i+1][1])/(a[i][0]-a[i+1][0]));
```

with

```
double slope=(double)((a[i][1]-a[i+1][1])/(a[i][0]-a[i+1][0]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
int a = 1 , b = 2;
```

this line of code:

```
double d = (double)(a/b);  // d is 0.
```

is *not* the same as:

```
double d = ((double)a/b);  // d is 0.5
```

In the first case, you are doing an integer division before converting the result.

In the second case, you are converting the numerator to a `double`, and *then* dividing, which does a floating point division.

In your case, the error might be coming about because the code expects a non-zero slope, but the integer division gives you a zero.

Note that this comparison:

```
 if( m!=slope)
```

is fundamentally flawed. You should never compare floating point numbers for equality. Use a threshold for the comparison instead.

Comment: So, instead can I rewrite it as :
if( abs(m-slope) > 1e-9

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats) question.