# why does c++ whole number checker not work properly?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to write a function that takes a `double` and multiplies it by 10 until it's an `int`.

here is the function:

```
int multiplyTillInt(double n){
  while(static_cast<int>(n) != n) {
    n *= 10;
  }
  return n;
}
```

expected behavior:

```
1.0 -> 1
8.296 -> 8296
.004 -> 4
32.999 -> 32999
```

however, this is not what's happening. the function behaves as expected for `double`s with 1 digit after the decimal point, but when i plug in a `double` with more than 1, sometimes it loops forever.

using `std::cout` to debug has not elucidated the problem. output for plugging in 8.29 is the following:

```
82.9
829
8290
82900
829000
8.29e+06
8.29e+07
8.29e+08
8.29e+09
8.29e+10
//continues along this vein eventually outputting only "inf"
```

as you can see, it completely ignores the point at which it should break the `while` loop. why is this happening?

Comment: Are you aware of how floating point numbers are stored in memory? And why exact equality comparison of 2 floating point numbers is very problematic?

Comment: You need to understand how floating-point numbers are stored to understand why this will not work. The trouble is that `82.9` is not representable exactly in IEEE floating point. What is actually stored is `82.90000000000000000000125` (or something like that). It is the closest representable value. When you print it the printing functions only print to so many decimal places and do rounding to be nice.

Comment: Look at the value of `n` after each multiplication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point numbers are usually represented by IEEE floating-point number (lets assume this for arguments case, even if it is not specified by the standard).

See: [IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

If you read the article, you will notice that anything below the decimal point is represented by a negative power of 2 (after shifting and all that).

```
 0.5   =>  1 bit one point below zero = 2^-1
 0.25  =>  1 bit two points below zero => 2^-2
 0.125 =>  1 bit three points below zero => 2^-3
 etc.
```

So the sub integer part of your number needs to be the sum of these bits. Assuming you have no integer part it needs to fit in 52 consecutive bits (53 because they do some clever optimization shit).

So lets look at `8.296`.

The integer bit (8) is: 1000 So we have used 4 bits (3 because of optimization). So we have 49 bits to represent the 0.296.

```
    Bits Below zero   Value    Amount Left     Bit Set or Not
          -             -           0.296            -
          1            0.5          0.296            0
          2            0.25         0.046            1
          3            0.125        0.046            0
          4            0.0625       0.046            0
          5            0.03125      0.01475          1
          6            0.015625     0.01475          0
          7            0.0078125    0.0069375        1
          8            0.00390625   0.00303125       1
          9            0.001953125  0.001078125      1
         10            0.0009765625 0.0001015625     1
         etc  // thus numbers coule be wrong I did it by hand.
         we have another 39 bits to go.


     8.296 = 10000100101111<another 39 bits>
             Then add an exponent to shift it so only
             have one bit above zero.
```

If I do the same loop and also print out the difference from zero.

```
NewVal:               82.96 diff from zero: 0.95999999999999375
NewVal:               829.6 diff from zero: 0.59999999999993747
NewVal:                8296 diff from zero: 0.99999999999937472
NewVal:               82960 diff from zero: 0.99999999999374722
NewVal:           8.296e+05 diff from zero: 0.99999999993747224
NewVal:           8.296e+06 diff from zero: 0.99999999937472239
NewVal:           8.296e+07 diff from zero: 0.99999999374995241
NewVal:           8.296e+08 diff from zero: 0.99999993748497218
```

Notice how the new number gets closer to zero (but then starts moving away (this is because we are loosing precision and bits of the end).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int multiplyTillInt(long double n)
{
    while(static_cast<int>(n) != n) {
        n *= 10;
        std::cout << "NewVal: "
                  << std::setw( 19 ) << std::setprecision( 5 ) << n
                  << " diff from zero: "
                  << std::setw( 19 ) << std::setprecision( 17 ) << (n - static_cast<int>(n)) << "\n";
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    multiplyTillInt(8.296);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimal floating point numbers can't be stored precisely. That `829` is only printed like that for convenience, actually it's something like `829.0000001`, so it doesn't equal the int `829` and doesn't break the loop.

To handle these rounding errors, you'll have to use something like `std::abs((double)i - d) > 1E-10` instead of `i != d`

Comment: use `std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1) << n;` to see this

Comment: this doesn't work. i tried

Comment: @HiddenToad sorry, that's just a general idea off the top of my head, not tested. My answer is very brief. Now that you know the problem, you can google best practices for comparing floats in C++

Answer (score 0):

See floating point numbers equality comparison.

Look at this for explanation [How should I do floating point comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

And this for C++ code examples [How to correctly and standardly compare floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats)

Comment: Unfortunately that comparison does not work. As he multiplies the number he looses 4 bits of precision each iteration. So the number gets further away from the epsilon if it does not hit it very quickly.