# Fixing Ray-Casting algorithm

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, raycasting

I've been trying to practice Ray-casting algorithm.  I'm facing 2 problems:

1. My casting ray does not align with the player's point of view and represent incorrectly the feature of a casting ray(ex: it will get short if hit a wall)
2. Sometime my program get crashed with this 'Error -1073741819' message.

Here are some pictures for my problem:

[Ray-cast problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM6zP.png)

[Program crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xcV2.png)

Here is my code using SDL library and C++ in VSC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define PI 3.1415926535

using namespace std;

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
SDL_Surface* surface;
float pdX, pdY, pA;
bool RunState;
int vel = 10;
int mapX = 8, mapY = 9, mapS = 64;
SDL_Rect tileRect = {0, 0, 64, 64};
int map[] = 
{
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,
    1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
};

class Player{
    public:
        SDL_Rect dest = {100, 100, 10, 10};
};

Player player;

void DrawRay3d()
{
    int r, mx, my, mp, dof;
    float rx, ry, ra, xo, yo;
    ra = pA;
    for(r = 0; r > -1; r--)
    {
        dof = 0;
        float aTan = -1/tan(ra);
        if(ra>PI)
        {
            ry = (((int)pdY/64)*64)-0.0001;
            rx = (pdY-ry)*aTan+pdX;
            yo = -64;
            xo= -yo*aTan;
        }
        if(ra<PI)
        {
            ry = (((int)pdY/64)*64)+64;
            rx = (pdY-ry)*aTan+pdX;
            yo = 64;
            xo= -yo*aTan;
        }
        if(ra==0 || ra==PI)
        {
            rx = pdX;
            ry = pdY;
            dof = 8;
        }
        while(dof<8)
        {
            mx = (int)(rx)/64;
            my = (int)(ry)/64;
            mp = my*mapX+mx;
            if(mp<mapX*mapY && map[mp]==1)
            {
                dof = 8;
            }
            else{
                rx += xo;
                ry += yo;
                dof +=1;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, player.dest.x+player.dest.w/2+pdX*5, player.dest.y+player.dest.h/2+pdY*5, rx, ry);
    }
}

void Drawmap()
{
    for(int y = 0; y < mapY; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < mapX; x++)
        {
            if(map[y*mapX+x]==1) 
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                tileRect.x = x*64;
                tileRect.y = y*64;
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &tileRect);

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64, y*64, x*64 + 64, y*64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64+64, y*64, x*64 + 64, y*64 + 64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64 + 64, y*64 + 64, x*64, y*64 + 64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64, y*64 + 64, x*64, y*64);
            }
            else if(map[y*mapX+x]==0) 
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
                tileRect.x = x*64;
                tileRect.y = y*64;
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &tileRect);

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64, y*64, x*64 + 64, y*64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64+64, y*64, x*64 + 64, y*64 + 64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64 + 64, y*64 + 64, x*64, y*64 + 64);
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x*64, y*64 + 64, x*64, y*64);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]){

    //Initialize window
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("RayCastin'", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1024, 512, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if(window)
    {
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if(renderer)
        {
            RunState = true;
            surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        }
    }

    //Looping
    while(RunState)
    {
        //Handel event
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            RunState = false;
        }
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_UP:
                    player.dest.y+=pdY;
                    player.dest.x+=pdX;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    player.dest.y-=pdY;
                    player.dest.x-=pdX;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    pA-=0.1;
                    if(pA<0) pA+=2*PI;
                    pdX=cos(pA)*vel; pdY = sin(pA)*vel;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    pA+=0.1;
                    if(pA>2*PI) pA-=2*PI;
                    pdX=cos(pA)*vel; pdY = sin(pA)*vel;
                    break;
            }
        }

        //Render
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        
        Drawmap();
        DrawRay3d();

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player.dest);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, player.dest.x+player.dest.w/2, player.dest.y+player.dest.h/2,  player.dest.x+player.dest.w/2+pdX*5, player.dest.y+player.dest.h/2+pdY*5);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please refer here 1st: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question really.
But I see some serious problems with your code.

1. You should try to declare variables only in places where they are used.
2. Then you should initialize all variables.
3. If you don't have a proper initialization for you pointers, just initialize them with *nullptr*. Try to give your variables meaningful names. x, y, rx, ... just seems wrong and trying to distinguish between them is hard.
4. Try also avoiding using namespace std. Here is why: [Avoid using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)!
5. The only programmatic flaw I see the loss of precision that is caused by some of your statements. Maybe that results in the error?

   ry = (((int)pdY/64)*64)-0.0001; This expression for example uses integer division and therefore omits precision.

   ```
        if(ra==0 || ra==PI)
   ```

This expression is error-prone. Try not to compare to floating point numbers. This generally does not work. You almost always want to introduce a number span, so they can be compared properly using an epsilon. If you want to know how this works. Here are some beginner-friendly introductions:

[LearnCPP.com](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/relational-operators-and-floating-point-comparisons/)

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats)